# Не показываются сообщение из службы

Tags: delphi, службы

Ставлю службу, там выводится ShowMessage с надписью "АГА". Потом я меняю дату на день вперёд должен вывестись ShowMessage с надписью "АГУ", но не чего не выводится. Зато когда удаляешь службу то окно "Агу" выводится!

Таймер установлен на интервал: 1

MainUnit.pas:

```
unit MainUnit;
interface
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.SvcMgr, Vcl.Dialogs, IniFiles, SHFolder,
  IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHTTP, FileCtrl,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TSupServUpdateService = class(TService)
    UpdateTimer: TTimer;
    IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
    procedure ServiceAfterInstall(Sender: TService);
    procedure UpdateTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
  public
    procedure GetSend;
    procedure GetSend1;
    function GetServiceController: TServiceController; override;
  end;

var
  SupServUpdateService: TSupServUpdateService;
  Get: string;
  a: tdate;
const
  UPDATE_NAME = 'cfg';

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

function GetAppDataDir: string;
var
  Path: array [0..MAX_PATH] of char;
const
  SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT = 0;
begin
  if SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(0, CSIDL_APPDATA, 0, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, @Path[0])) then
    Result := Path
  else
    Result := '';
  end;

procedure ServiceController(CtrlCode: DWord); stdcall;
begin
  SupServUpdateService.Controller(CtrlCode);
end;

procedure TSupServUpdateService.GetSend;
begin
  showmessage('Ага!!!');
end;

procedure TSupServUpdateService.GetSend1;
begin
  showmessage('Агу!!');
end;

function TSupServUpdateService.GetServiceController: TServiceController;
begin
  Result := ServiceController;
end;

procedure TSupServUpdateService.ServiceAfterInstall(Sender: TService);
var
  CheckAfterInstall: TIniFile;
begin
  CheckAfterInstall:= TIniFile.Create(GetAppDataDir + '\' + UPDATE_NAME + 'ServiceUpdate');
  CheckAfterInstall.WriteDate('Data', 'EndCheck', Date);
  GetSend;
end;

procedure TSupServUpdateService.UpdateTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
var
  CheckUpdate, Check: TIniFile;
  FileDate: TDate;
   A: tdatetime;
begin
  CheckUpdate:= TIniFile.Create(GetAppDataDir + '\' + UPDATE_NAME + 'ServiceUpdate');
  FileDate:= CheckUpdate.ReadDate('Data', 'EndCheck', Date);

  if Date > FileDate then
    begin
      Check:= TIniFile.Create(GetAppDataDir + '\' + UPDATE_NAME + 'ServiceUpdate');
      Check.WriteDate('Data', 'EndCheck', Date);
      GetSend1;
      //DeleteFile('c:\2.txt');
    end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Есть подозрение что повторное срабатывание таймера игнорируется системой или реализацией стандартной оконной процедуры в VCL до тех пор пока на закончится обработка предыдущего срабатывания. А Закрыть окно с сообщением за 1 мс вы точно не успеете. Попробуйте вывести что-то в файл или в `OutputDebugString`. А лучше поставить интервал в несколько секунд.

Answer (score 3):

Начиная с Windows Vista все сервисы работают на отдельном "служебном" рабочем столе, который не имеет доступа к рабочему столу пользователя.

Поэтому сообщение из сервиса, даже если у него выставлен флаг "интерактивности" не видно.
Чтобы показать что-либо пользователю нужно запустить процесс именно в оконной станции и на рабочем столе пользователя, что из сервиса сделать не так-то просто.

P.S. интервал 1 в таймере - это слишком мало. Минимально возможный интервал в ОС Windows составляет 16 миллисекунд ( https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer ), поэтому меньшие значения выставлять смысла нет.

Comment: Часть про интервал вы тестировали сами? ибо заявление от реальности оторвано.
https://yadi.sk/i/yLTrGYVq9fPaYw

Comment: Стандартное разрешение интервала около 16мс. Снижается до 1мс если запросить begin time period (емнип)

Comment: Таймер на 1мс срабатывает как через 0мс, так и через стандартный для машины/ОС интервал с разной вероятностью. Средний интервал срабатываний в течение достаточно продолжительного времени будет стремится к заданному интервалу (1мс в данном случае). Проверено на Win7, 8, 10.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci это всё зависит от железа и нагрузки на него, само переключение занимает микросекунды(на разных процессорах по разному) и если у ОС есть свободные ресурсы, которые нечем нагружать - таймер будет срабатывать и чаще чем 1мс.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков вы проверяли свое утверждение?

Comment: @kot-da-vinci, Kromster, ВладимирКлыков  . Да, с 40мс - погорячился, каюсь. Тем не менее - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer говорит о 16мс. Отредактировал ответ, спасибо за замечание !

Comment: @kot-da-vinci Которое из них? про переключение размером в микросекунды? - нет, доверился документации Intel, про свободные ресурсы и срабатывание таймера чаще чем раз в 1мс? - на стандартном таймере - нет, необходимости ниразу небыло. в таймере на потоках(c уходом потока в sleep) - да.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Sleep не срабатывает чаще при отсутствии нагрузки.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci, да вы правы, откопал старые исходники, там был не sleep а хак на околослиповую тему с использованием ring 0 драйвера.

Comment: Не помогло увеличение интервала, в vcl приложении нормально работает а в службе нет

Comment: @AimonZralt основная часть ответа относится не к интервалу таймера. Не зря он (таймер) вынесен в постскриптум. А к тому, что из службы вы не сможете выполнить задуманное. Не может служба достучаться до рабочего стола пользователя. Нет у нее таких полномочий.

Comment: А почему при установке она это всё делает

Comment: Да и я заметил если просто написать showmessage('fff'); то всё работает сообщение показываются, а если так if 1=1 then showmessage('fff');  то уже нет если ставишь какие-то условия то не работает?

Comment: @AimonZralt Установка и удаление службы - отдельные операции, они производятся в пользовательском контексте.